# How to check if file is being uploaded with multer

Tags: node.js

I am uploading a file using `multer` but the problem is as I am trying to check if it's being uploaded or not using `if (req.body.file)` the app will not crash but the browser will say that the page is not available. Is there another way of checking if the file will be uploaded?

Comment: can you add the code you have done so far?

Comment: With multer file is available on the request object with `req.file` or `req.files` if multiple and not on `req.body.file`

Answer (score 1):

```
    var multer = require('multer');

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
     //multers disk storage settings
     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'public/uploads/')
     },
     filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      //var datetimestamp = Date.now();
      cb(null, file.originalname)
     }
    });
    var upload = multer({
     storage: storage
    })

    router.post('/adduser', upload.single('image'), function (req, res) {
     console.log(req.body.name);
     var data = {
      name: req.body.name,
      password: req.body.password,
      image: 'uploads/' + req.file.originalname
     }
     users.insert(data, function (err, data) {
      console.log(data);
      res.redirect('/home');
     });
    });
    <form action="/adduser" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="text" name="name" />
       <input type="password" name="password" />
       <input type="file" name="image" />
       <input type="submit">
    </form>
```